# java.sql.SQLException: near "on": syntax error problem

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, prepared-statement

In Sqlite 3.6.0, I want to update record if exist or insert.But I am getting an error as

```
java.sql.SQLException: near "on": syntax error
```

my sql query as follows;

```
INSERT INTO tx (
               _id,
               amount,
               fee,
               prev_hash,
               nonce,
               action_time,
               completion_time,
               _from,
               _to,
               asset,
               hash,
               block,
               seq,
               [desc]
           )
           VALUES (
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?,
               ?
           )
           ON CONFLICT (
               _id
           )
           DO UPDATE SET amount = 1.0,
           fee = 0.001,
           prev_hash = 'e6d0ca4b71488972cb149eef427ffbeb6132449c045c88db89ddaa8ab0c3611f',
           nonce = 1544773280,
           action_time = 1544773276808,
           completion_time = 1544773276808,
           _from = 'SKK1P5eQqoN7FBKnughbvp3UBK2CyjRQhHBp',
           _to = 'SKK1KuAwe4kR1SfdoXDiQStVtRPvdTVaKy2ry',
           asset = 'SKK',
           hash = '',
           block = 100,
           seq = 15288,
           [desc] = 'denemee'
```

And my code block as follws;

```
sql = "insert into tx (_id,amount,fee,prev_hash,nonce,action_time,completion_time,_from,_to,asset,hash,block,seq,desc) "
                                    + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) on conflict (_id) do update set "
                                    + "amount =" + tx.amount + ",fee=" + tx.fee + ",prev_hash='" + tx.prev_hash
                                    + "'" + ",nonce=" + tx.nonce + ",action_time=" + tx.action_time
                                    + ",completion_time=" + tx.action_time + ",_from='" + tx.wallet + "'" + ",_to='"
                                    + tx.to + "'" + ",asset='" + tx.asset + "'" + ",hash=''" + ",block=100"
                                    + ",seq=" + tx.seq + ",desc='" + tx.desc + "'";
                            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                            pstmt.setString(1, tx._id);
                            pstmt.setString(2, String.valueOf(tx.amount));
                            pstmt.setString(3, String.valueOf(tx.fee));// fee
                            pstmt.setString(4, tx.prev_hash);// prev_hash
                            pstmt.setString(5, tx.nonce);// nonce
                            pstmt.setString(6, String.valueOf(tx.action_time));// action time
                            pstmt.setString(7, "");// completion_time
                            pstmt.setString(8, tx.wallet);// from
                            pstmt.setString(9, tx.to); // to
                            pstmt.setString(10, tx.asset);// asset
                            pstmt.setString(11, tx.hash);// hash
                            pstmt.setString(12, "");// block
                            pstmt.setInt(13, tx.seq);// seq
                            pstmt.setString(14, tx.desc);// desc
                            pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

the raw query works at sqlitestudio successfully, but I am getting an error.I know that sqlite version 3.6.0 supports upsert event.Where am I doing wrong.How can I handle this problem properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is due to

> I know that sqlite version 3.6.0 supports upsert event.

The use of `INSERT..... ON CONFLICT .... DO....` (what is termed as **UPSERT**) is only available from version 3.24.0.

Attempting to use **UPSERT** (DO.....), in version prior to 3.24.0 will result in the **`syntax error at ON`**

as per

> UPSERT is a special syntax addition to INSERT that causes the INSERT
>   to behave as an UPDATE or a no-op if the INSERT would violate a
>   uniqueness constraint. UPSERT is not standard SQL. UPSERT in SQLite
>   follows the syntax established by PostgreSQL. UPSERT syntax was added
>   to SQLite with version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04).
>
> An UPSERT is an ordinary INSERT statement that is followed by the
>   special ON CONFLICT clause shown above.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - upsert](https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html)

You need to either use an SQLite version that is 3.24.0 or greater or find an alternative approach.

Comment: but i understand my sqlite jar version 3.6.0.
So version 3.6.0 version is higher than 3.24.
Is it normal to get such an error.

Comment: @Baltazar Ok then I'll give you 6 million dollars when you give me the lower 24 million dollars? Or perhaps read [Version Numbers in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/versionnumbers.html).

Comment: Ohh, you're right.
I'm confused about the versions.
But I couldn't find the jar of version 3.24.
Are you aware of this?

Comment: @Baltazar sorry but I just go with whatever version the tools I use come with and as most of my work is on Android I tend to stay clear of newer features. P.S. 3.26.0 is out now.

Comment: Ok thanks very much.I find the version at http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.25.2/